# Very basic bingo game

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and programming as a whole and i have a quick question to ask you guys, I've searched a bit but only found far too complicated examples for me to implement in my work so here goes:

```
        int[] newArray = new int[7];
        Console.WriteLine("Hello! Please enter 7 numbers between 1-25, press ENTER after each number. ");
        for (int i = 0; i < newArray.Length; i++)
            bool loop = true;
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    newArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    loop = false;
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You may only enter numbers!");  
                }
            } while (loop);
        Console.Write("You entered the following numbers: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < newArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(newArray[i]);
        }
    }
```

This is the first part of a bingogame im trying to write, but i can't understand why the names loop and i don't exist, should i make something static? Move some brackets around? Please help.

Comment: use braces `{ }` for `for`

Comment: Please read [ask]. _"the names loop and i don't exist"_ isn't a proper problem description. Include the actual compiler errors, all relevant code and what you have tried.

Comment: If you let your IDE do the indentation, instead of doing it yourself, you'll get a very valuable clue to fix the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by "i can't understand why the names loop"?

Comment: This doesn't happen with proper indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the entire `for` statement in braces, otherwise it will only execute the next line of code, which is just `bool loop = true;`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < newArray.Length; i++)
{ // <-- Add this
  bool loop = true;
  do
  {
    try
    {
      newArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      loop = false;
    }
    catch
    {
      Console.WriteLine("You may only enter numbers!");  
    }
  } while (loop);

  Console.Write("You entered the following numbers: ");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's worth to mention about string.Join method to print all elements of the list.

```
Console.WriteLine("You entered the following numbers: ");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", newArray));
```

After using **Parse**/**TryParse** method, you don't need to use Convert.ToInt32 any more.

To validate number and be able to reenter it, it is much better to do 2 IF statements instead of using **Constains** method of Enumerable class.

```
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number) || number < 1 || number > 25)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You may only enter numbers from range 1-25!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make one single bracket right after your for cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an open brace. This looks like homework so I'm not going to rewrite it for you. Take a closer look and work on the formatting and indentations. That will give you a clue as to were that missing brace should be.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nicer way to test for number input without the try/catch

```
var newArray = new int[7];
Console.WriteLine("Hello! Please enter 7 numbers between 1-25, press ENTER after each number. ");
for (var i = 0; i <= newArray.Length - 1; i++)
{
    int number;
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You may only enter numbers!");
    }

    newArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(number);
}

Console.WriteLine("You entered the following numbers: ");
foreach (var t in newArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas i tried this out and it worked swell, problem is i now also want to check wether the numbers input by the user is in the range of 1-25, the way i was thinking of doing this was using:
 if (Enumerable.Range(1,25).Contains(number))
Although Visual studio then told me number is not in the current context. Why?

Comment: Ok, i managed to make it check if the numbers were between 1 and 25 now, although only so that it places a 0 instead of the faulty input. How do i prompt a reenter? This is what i did:

                }
                if (Enumerable.Range(1, 25).Contains(number))
                {
                    newArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(number);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You may only enter numbers between 1 and 25!");
                }
            }